# PHP: Can't insert 'the_title()' in "title" & "alt" attributes in 'the_post_thumbnail' (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <?php $attr = 'Is ' . the_title() . ' a good computer?'; ?>
    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', ['title' => $attr, 'alt' => $attr]); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

produces output:

```
<p><img width="300" height="300" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/image.jpg" alt="Is  a good computer?" title="Is  a good computer?" ></p>
```

Why isn't `the_title()` being included?

Help appreciated.

Comment: you might want to look into the differences between `the_title()` and `get_the_title()`. there are multiple wordpress functions like this; the functions prefixed with `get_` return a value and the ones without it will echo the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `the_title()` **prints** the title immediately when it’s called, it doesn’t return its value for use in other functions. Use `get_the_title()` instead, which returns its value:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <?php $attr = 'Is ' . get_the_title() . ' a good computer?'; ?>
    <p><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', ['title' => $attr, 'alt' => $attr]); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Like many similarly-named WordPress functions, `the_title()` actually calls `get_the_title()` to echo the return value. [From documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/):

```
function the_title( $before = '', $after = '', $echo = true ) {
    $title = get_the_title();
    if ( strlen($title) == 0 )
        return;
    $title = $before . $title . $after;
    if ( $echo )
        echo $title;
    else
        return $title;
}
```

WordPress Documentation:

[the_title() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/)

[get_the_title() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)